# Print a two dimension list with format in Python

Tags: python

So I have defined a two dimension list in python using:

```
column = 3
row = 2
Matrix =  [['' for i in range(column)] for j in range(row)]
```

Then I started adding values to it:

```
Matrix[0][0] += 'A'
Matrix[1][0] += 'AB'
Matrix[2][0] += 'ABC'
Matrix[0][1] += 'X'
Matrix[1][1] += 'XY'
Matrix[2][1] += 'XYZ'
```

Then I started printing with hope of some sort of format:

```
for i in range(0, row, 1):
    for j in range(0, column, 1):
        print(Matrix[i][j] + '\t')
```

I was thinking of get result like

```
A   AB   ABC
X   XY   XYZ
```

But actually I got:

```
A   
AB  
ABC     
X   
XY  
XYZ
```

Just wondering what is wrong with my code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only want a new line each `i`, and *not* each `j`. Generally they're implicit, so you need to specify no newline:

### Python 3:

```
for i in range(0, row, 1):
    for j in range(0, column, 1):
        print(Matrix[i][j] + '\t', end="")  # <-- end="" means no newline
    print('')  # <-- implicit newline, only in row loop
```

### Python 2:

```
for i in range(0, row, 1):
    for j in range(0, column, 1):
        print Matrix[i][j] + '\t',  # <-- comma at the end means no newline
    print('')  # <-- implicit newline, only in row loop
```

Comment: This assumes python3x

Answer (score 5):

the `print` function adds a newline to the end.

a way to signal that you dont want a new line is to use add a comma at the end

**Python 3**

```
print(Matrix[i][j],"\t",)
```

**Python 2.7**

```
print Matrix[i][j],"\t",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sep` argument in python3:

```
for row in zip(*Matrix):
    print(*row, sep='\t')
```

You have the rows as columns in your matrix, so you'll need to zip it to get at the rows first.
Then, you can print the individual elements in the row, with a <kbd>TAB</kbd> between them

In python2, this would be:

import itertools
for row in itertools.izip(*Matrix):
    print('\t'.join(row))

Answer (score 1):

First you may want to check how you added your values.  While 
iterating over the row, you will receive an '`IndexError: list out of range`'

Adding your values should look like this:

```
Matrix[0][0] = 'A'
Matrix[0][1] = 'AB'
Matrix[0][2] = 'ABC'
Matrix[1][0] = 'X'
Matrix[1][1] = 'XY'
Matrix[1][2] = 'XYZ'
```

After that, then all you have to do is iterate over your rows using the method `join()` on each row.

```
for i in range(row):
  print '\t'.join(Matrix[i])
```

That will print your desired result:

```
A   AB  ABC
X   XY  XYZ
```

Comment: Thank you for the other method,and I am not receiving the 'list out of range" error~

Comment: And this seems not working perfectly, if using "print '\t'.join(Matrix[i]),", actually it is missing a '\n' after the 'ABC'